# How to convert object into datetime in Pandas

Tags: pandas, tableau-desktop

I'm playing around with Pandas and Tableau to create time series from UK unemployment stats.

I've carved the data and have something like this:

```
Index  Date      Count
158    1992 APR 501
159    1992 MAY 507
160    1992 JUN 509
161    1992 JUL 509
```

Want to use pd.to_datetime() method but it keeps coming back with error:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the date object to following and it works:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```